# the unit digit for $3^{100}\cdot 37^{98}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the best  way to know the unit digit for $3^{100}\cdot 37^{98}$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
37 * 3 & \equiv 1 \text{ (mod 10)}\\
(37 * 3)^n & \equiv 1 \text{ (mod 10)}\\
(37 * 3)^{98} & \equiv 1 \text{ (mod 10)}\\
(37 * 3)^{98} * 3^2 & \equiv 1 * 3^2 \text{ (mod 10)}\\
or, 37^{98} * 3^{100} & \equiv 9 \text{ (mod 10)}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Definitely the best way, kudos, $37 \cdot 3 = 111$...

Comment: One can avoid even working out $37 \cdot 3$ by using the fact that mod 10, $37 \cdot 3 \equiv 7 \cdot 3 \equiv 21$.

Answer (score 5):

First find the unit digit pattern of numbers being multiplied by $3$, starting with $3$.

$$ 3, 9, 7, 1, 3, 9, ... $$

Now do the same for $7$

$$ 7, 9, 3, 1, 7, 9, ... $$

Now find the $100^{th}$ and $98^{th}$ element respectively of each of those sequences and multiply them together.

Answer (score 5):

We essentially need $3^{100}\cdot37^{98}\pmod{10}$

$3^4=81\equiv1\pmod{10}$ or

using [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem),  $3^4\equiv1\pmod{10}$ as $\phi(10)=\phi(2)\phi(5)=4$

$\implies 3^{4n}\equiv1$

Also, $37\equiv7\pmod{10}\implies 37^{98}\equiv7^{98}\pmod{10}$

Again, using Fermat's Little Theorem  $7^4\equiv1\pmod{10}\implies 7^{4n}\equiv1$

So,  $3^{100}\cdot37^{98}=(3^4)^{25}\cdot(7^4)^{24}\cdot7^2\equiv1\cdot1\cdot9\pmod{10}$

Comment: Technically, Fermat's Little Theorem gives you $3^{5-1}\equiv1\pmod{5}\implies 3^{4n}\equiv1$, which of course implies the mod 10 congruence. But really you don't need it at all, as we know the values here, as is pointed out in your second line.

Comment: @ChrisHartman, agreed & rectified

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ 10\!:\,\ 37\equiv 7\equiv 3^{-1}\!\Rightarrow\: 3^{100}37^{98}\!\equiv 3^{100} 3^{-98}\!\equiv 3^2$